# Android Sharedpreferences Updating Only After App Restart

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Good Day,

I have read almost all posts in regards with Sharedpreferences on Stackoverflow but none of them seems to answer my question.

I store a Token code in Sharedpreferences after getting it from JSON, when I toast the values all is correct, then I save the string value to Sharedpreferences with the below code:

```
private String mypreference = "AppData.xml";
private String KeySave = "KeySave";

sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(mypreference, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String Token = json.optString("TokenFomJSON");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(KeySave, Token);
                        editor.commit();
```

When I look at the XML I can see the saved value, the problem is when I convert the Sharedpreferences again back to String to be used with the below code:

```
String KeyCaptured = sharedpreferences.getString(KeySave, "");
```

Then it returns the previous saved key and not the updated one from JSON.

When I restart the application, then the correct key is displayed.

What I have done testing this far.

Changing .commit() to .apply()

I 1st call the JSON via the code below:

```
GetKey();

private void GetKey() {
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(
            Request.Method.POST, url, js,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d("Token", response.toString());
                    try {
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                        String Token = json.optString("TokenFomJSON");

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putString(KeySave , Token);
                        editor.commit();
                      //  Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, Token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d("Token", "Error: " + error.getMessage());
        }
    })
```

}

Then I call it with the below code:

```
String KeyCaptured = sharedpreferences.getString(KeySave, "");
```

Other than the above that I have tested, there is not many other suggestions to try, anyone else got some suggestions I could try?

Thank You,
Kind Regards

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Please add few more code based information, so that we can have overall idea. Would be better to find the solution.

Comment: `When I look at the XML I can see the saved value`. It is unclear to me what you do if you 'look at the XLM'.

Comment: I store the values in a xml "private String mypreference = "AppData.xml"; , when I use an editor I can see the updated JSON values saved there.

Comment: What is KeySave? What is Token? They cannot be String variables as the java convention asks to let variable names start with lower case.

Comment: Both is Strings, KeySave is the String name allocated to the SharedPref and Token is the String value that I save against KeySave that I receive from the JSON.

Comment: `"private String mypreference = "AppData.xml";` Put that in your code. This has been asked twice before. Also put the value of the other strings in your code. `when I use an editor I` It is unclear to me what you do when you would use an editor on a shared preferences file.

Comment: From where your code is called? Background thread? Foreground? That may be an issue.

Comment: I call it in Foreground, onCreate.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out, I needed to give a delay of 2 sec between the JSON and the request. All working now